# Guardar configuracion de la aplicacion Laravel

Tags: laravel, web

Necesito guardar la configuración de mi aplicación en Laravel, hasta el sol de hoy solo lo he intentado con Base de datos, creando una tabla de se llame config, y con dos columnas, una llamada "name" de tipo, y la otra llamada Value, que corresponde al valor de esa configuración, no se si esta es la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero es la única que se me ha ocurrido, si alguien me puede ayudar con esto, se lo agredesco.

Comment: ¿Con qué finalidad la quieres guardar en una base de datos y no en los archivos que ya tiene laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de que información planees guardar, la forma en la que indicas en una tabla en base de datos, esta se podría usar para la configuración de la sesión de un usuario de una aplicación.

De otra manera se me ocurren dos opciones:

1. Meter tus variables en tu archivo `.env` (No se que tipo de configuración sea, pero esto solo es para variables de entorno).
2. Incluir en `public/index.php` un archivo que tenga todas tus variables, por ejemplo: en `public/index.php` añades una línea `require_once(__DIR__.'/ruta/a/mis/variables.php');` y dentro de `variables.php` definir tus variables de esta manera `define('_Max_results', '1000');` de esta manera ya puedes utilizar `_Max_results` o cualquiera de tus variables en tus archivos.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del directorio config/ puedes crear todos los archivos de configuracion que quieras y luegos los llamas Config::(archivo.valor); . En este punto recuerda importar config (use Config;)

Tambien puedes agregar configuraciones en el archivo .env (recuerda tambienta agregar estos campos en .env.example asi si hay que clonar nuevamente ya van esos valores en el .env por defecto). En este caso para llamar a esos valores usas env('valor')

Espero te ayude,
saludos

Comment: Y como las modificaria?

Comment: Puedes editar directamente el archivo .env o puedes instalar algun composer extra como puede ser dotenv/editor el cual te añade una interfaz grafica y desde ahi puedes editar directamente el archivo .env sin tener que entrar al servidor.